# Does the Bowcaster kill in one shot?

Tags: xbox-one, star-wars-battlefront-2015

I realized that the bowcaster was recently nerfed (I'm playing on XBox One), but does it still kill in one shot?

Comment: Test it perhaps? Or ask someone who has one to test it on you?

Comment: it's not easy to test, and my connection lags a lot, so i dont always even hit. that why i'm asking it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to before the nerf. Now, if you can get the whole spread (or what appears to be most of it) to hit them in the head, yes, it will kill them in one shot.

But that's very hard and very unlikely.